# UI-Router and Query Parameters in a Redirect

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using angular's ui-router, is there a way to write redirects, such that query parameters will be populated for the target state. For example, here's my state:

```
.state('me.profile', {
  url: '/profile?action',
  templateUrl: '/app/components/account/profile/profile.html',
  controller: 'profileCtrl',
  authenticate: true
})
```

Specific actions can be passing in via query parameter. For example:

```
examplesite.com/profile?action=editProfile
```

However, I wish to be able to provide pretty URLs for the user. Example:

```
examplesite.com/profile/edit
```

Can I write a redirect statement, that populates the desired query parameters on that route. The following code is **not currently working**, since the query param `?action=editPayment` gets lost when the user is redirected to the target state.

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/profile/edit', '/profile?action=editProfile');
```

Comment: Do want to go same url with different parameters? How will you decide action. Is it possible ot have something like that $urlRouterProvider.when('/profile/payment', '/profile?action=createPayment');

Comment: @PoyrazYilmaz Action will be passed in by the original URL. So, /profile/edit will auto-resolve to /profile?action=edit. Unfortunately, in the example you wrote, the query params don't make it to the final state.

Answer (score 2):

Inplace of `?action` Change it to:

```
url: '/profile/:action',
```

Inject `$stateParams` and read the action in your controller

```
 var action = $stateParams.action;
```

Comment: If designing from the ground up, this would be the proper solution. However, this new route will break all existing URLs to ``/profile``. I would need to add a redirect for ``/profile`` -> ``/profile/`` (trailing slash). This might end up being my final solution if I can't find another method.